# R: from a column range from 1 to 10 to a column to 0 and 1

Tags: r

I just started using R and I've encountered a problem: I have a column with different rows that go from 1 to 10. I want to create a new column where all the values < of 6 are now 0 and all the values >= 6 are now 1. Could you please help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Use `df1$newcol <- +(df1$col >=6)`

Comment: A couple more options of increasing wordiness: `df1$newcol <- as.integer(df1$col >= 6)`, `df1$newcol <- ifelse(df1$col >= 6, 1, 0)` (less efficient, but nice and clear).